# $\rm SU(2)$ isospin invariance of the nucleon-pion system in infinitesimal transformation for Noether current calculation

Tags: particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, nuclear-physics, group-theory

I'm reading ["Dynamics of the Standard Model, Cambridge monographs on particle physics, nuclear physics and cosmology"](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511803512).

In page 10 the authors achieve an expression for the Lagrangian which is the following:
$$\mathcal{L}'(\hat{\psi},\hat{\pi})=\mathcal{L}(\hat{\psi},\hat{\pi})+\frac{1}{2}\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\boldsymbol{\tau}\cdot\partial_\mu\boldsymbol{\alpha}\psi-\epsilon^{ijk}(\partial_\mu\pi^i)\pi^j\partial^\mu\alpha_k$$

I can obtain the first two terms, the one I'm having trouble getting is the last one.
The pion transforms as $\hat\pi^i=\pi^i-\epsilon^{ijk}\pi^j\alpha^k(x)$ and the Lagrangian is: $$\mathcal{L}=\bar\psi(i {\partial\!\!\!/} -\boldsymbol{m})\psi+\frac{1}{2}[\partial_\mu\boldsymbol\pi\partial^\mu\boldsymbol\pi -m_\pi^2\boldsymbol{\pi}\cdot\boldsymbol{\pi}]+ig\bar\psi\boldsymbol\tau\cdot\boldsymbol\tau\gamma_5\psi-\frac{\lambda}{4}(\boldsymbol\pi\cdot\boldsymbol\pi)^2$$

I'm having trouble with the term: $$\partial_\mu\boldsymbol\pi\partial^\mu\boldsymbol\pi$$ which is the one where one obtains $$-\epsilon^{ijk}(\partial_\mu\pi^i)\pi^j\partial^\mu\alpha_k.$$

I obtain that term, but some extra terms that I don't know how to cancel. I have done the following:

$$(\partial_\mu\pi\partial^\mu\pi) {'}=(\partial_\mu\pi^i-\epsilon^{ijk}(\partial_\mu\pi^j)\alpha^k(x))(\partial^\mu\pi^i-\epsilon^{ijk}(\partial^\mu\pi^j)\alpha^k(x))=\\ \partial_\mu\pi^i\partial^\mu\pi^i-\partial_\mu\pi^i\epsilon^{ijk}(\partial^\mu\pi^j)\alpha^k(x)-\partial_\mu\pi^i\epsilon^{ijk}\pi^j(\partial^\mu\alpha^k(x))-\epsilon^{ijk}(\partial_\mu\pi^j)\alpha^k(x)(\partial^\mu\pi^i)+\epsilon^{ijk}\epsilon^{ijk}(\partial_\mu\pi^i)\alpha^{k^2}(x)(\partial^\mu\pi^j)+\epsilon^{ijk}\epsilon^{ijk}(\partial_\mu\pi^j)\alpha^k(x)\pi^j\partial^\mu\alpha^k(x)-\epsilon^{ijk}\pi^j(\partial_\mu\alpha^k(x))\partial^\mu\pi^i+\epsilon^{ijk}\epsilon^{ijk}\pi^j\partial_\mu\alpha^k(x)\partial^\mu\pi^j\alpha^k(x)+\epsilon^{ijk}\epsilon^{ijk}\pi^j\pi^j\partial_\mu\alpha^k(x)\partial^\mu\alpha^k(x)$$

How do I cancel the extra terms? Should I cancel every term that depends on $\alpha^2$?

Answer (score 1):

Terms like $$\partial_\mu\pi^i\epsilon^{ijk}(\partial^\mu\pi^j)\alpha^k(x)\\ \epsilon^{ijk}(\partial_\mu\pi^j)\alpha^k(x)(\partial^\mu\pi^i)$$

vanish since $\epsilon^{ijk}$ is totally antisymmetric and $\partial_\mu\pi^i\partial^\mu\pi^j$ is symmetric in the two indices.

Terms depending on $\alpha^2$ should be cancelled since the expansion should be done to first order.

Comment: I got the symmetric and anti-symmetric part, how do I get $\epsilon^{ijk}(\partial_\mu\pi^i)\pi^j\partial^\mu\alpha^k(x)$ from $\epsilon^{ijk}(\partial^\mu\pi^i)\pi^j\partial_\mu\alpha^k(x)$. Also what does it means to write $\alpha k$ instead of $\alpha^k(x)$

Comment: @fec In this context $\alpha k$ has no specific meaning while $\alpha^k$ is the k-th component of the $\alpha$ vector.
The two factors you wrote are identical, it's not important where the $\mu$ index is as long as they are contracted.